# Using an initializer in an unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli

I have a `stdlib` initializer. In that initializer, i reopen some of built-in Ember classes and add some custom methods. For example, i added `reverseEach` to `Ember.Enumerable` and `Array`.

They work fine in the app, but in tests i receive "reverseEach: undefined is not a function".

How do i indicate that the test should use the initializer?

I tried `needs: [..., 'initializer:stdlib']`. It does not stumble upon that, but i still receive the "undefined" error.

Here's an example test:

```
`import { test, moduleForModel } from 'ember-qunit'`

moduleForModel 'foo', 'foo',
  needs: [
    'model:bar'
    'initializer:stdlib'
  ]

test 'deleteLastNItems', ->
  model = @subject()
  model.set '', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux']
  model.deleteLastNItems 2 # This should not die with "reverseEach: undefined is not a function"
  deepEquals model.get('someProperty'), ['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ember g initializer stdlib`, it will generate sample code for you, including test.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { initialize } from '../../../initializers/stdlib';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

var registry, application;

module('Unit | Initializer | stdlib', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    Ember.run(function() {
      application = Ember.Application.create();
      registry = application.registry;
      application.deferReadiness();
    });
  }
});

// Replace this with your real tests.
test('it works', function(assert) {
  initialize(registry, application);

  // you would normally confirm the results of the initializer here
  assert.ok(true);
});
```

Refer: [Ember blueprints](http://www.ember-cli.com/extending/#developing-addons-and-blueprints)

Comment: The question is not how to test the initializer itself, but how to test another unit (e. g. model) that uses methods monkey-patched from the initializer.

Comment: en, you can extract thest monkey-patched method to a Ember.mixin, then import the Mixin instead of initializer.

Comment: I am monkey-patching Ember itself, not the model. For example, I add a new method to `Ember.MutableArray`: a `.destructiveMap()` method that modifies the given array rather than returning a new array.

Comment: In you example, i mean `import MutableArrayMixin` first, then `Ember.MutableArray.reopen(MutableArrayMixin)`, now MutableArray have method you define in MutableArrayMixin like destructiveMap etc. then write you test.

Comment: And do that every time I need a monkey-patched method? Note that it will persist, e. g. subsequent reopens will be useless. But you're not sure in which order your units will be evaluated, so you either have to meaninglessly repeat the reopening every time you're using a monkey-patched method, or you have to find one place that is certain to be evaluated before any use of the method. And such place is an initializer.

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov exactly what I am looking for. Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, but I would look into `tests/test-helper.js`.